# Inserir value de um radio button no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu tenho:

```
<label class="">
      <input name="user_perfil" type="radio" value="administrador">  Administrador
    </label>
    <label class="">
      <input name="user_perfil" type="radio" value="cliente">  Cliente
    </label>
```

E no meu banco de dados tenho uma coluna:
`enum('administrador', 'cliente', 'suporte_tecnico')`

Estou pegando o POST que contém o valor do radio button:
 `$perfil =   $_POST['user_perfil'];`

E estou chamando uma função:

```
function novoUsuario($conexao, $user, $password, $email, $nome, $perfil)
{
   $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email,     user_fullname, rank)
            VALUES ('{$user}', '{$user_password_hash}', '{$email}', '{$nome}', '{$perfil}')";
            return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
}
```

Porém no meu banco não está sendo salvo o valor do rank. Eu usarei esse rank para abrir páginas específicas para cada valor (adm, suporte, etc).

O que eu estou fazendo de errado meus amigos?

Comment: Verificou se o valor está chegando corretamente ao php? tipo: fazendo die($perfil), e alterando a opção selecionada?

Comment: Realmente parece tudo certo, debuga o valor que está chegando com o 'print_r($_POST)', se tiver indo os valores certos, debuga a query com o 'or die(mysqli_error())', tenta postar aqui os resultados disso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

César, parece que vc está fazendo tudo correto.Eu não achei nenhum erro. Estou entendendo que somente o valor da varável `$perfil` não está sendo inserido no mysql.
Eu sugiro fazer um debug.

1. Vamos ver se vc está recebendo o valor da variável corretamente.
2. Vamos testar a inserção no banco de dados com um valor qualquer.

Depois desses resultados poderemos determinar onde está o erro.

Use `echo "variável=>".$_POST['user_perfil'];` Se vc ver o valor no browser, a recuperação do valor do rádio está ok. Se não, o valor não está sendo recuperado corretamente.

Logo em seguida na próxima linha use `$perfil = "teste";` Se vc não ver o valor teste na sua tabela do banco de dados, é pq o problema se encontra a inserção. Se vc ver teste na sua tabela de banco de dados o problema é na fase anterior.

Uma outra coisa. Reveja o tamanho da **varchar(?)** na criação da tabela.

para vc verificar o erro na sua inserção aconselho usar o gerenciador de erros mo MysqLi
Adapte esse código a sua função caso não já tenha feito:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO .... "))
  {
     echo("Erro: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

Comment: Ele está utilizando enum, não tem tamanho, ele apenas aceita os termos que estão na lista

Comment: Correto, eu não prestei atenção a esse detalhe.

Comment: Zwitterion, boa tarde carinha!
Há alguns minutos fiz dois testes. O primeiro foi cadastrar um novo usuário sem fazer nenhuma modificação no código, resultado: rank não salvou no banco.
O segundo, adicionei um var_dump pra dar uma olhada no post como você me pediu, e a recuperação do _$POST está ok e a inserção ok também.
Olhei o banco, e tudo funcionou certinho. Tirei o var_dump e tudo está funcionando corretamente.
Agora fica a dúvida... Porquê antes não funcionou sendo que não mudei nada no código? O_O

Comment: Boa tarde..  acontece comigo tbm. De vez em quando tem um pequeno detalhe, uma vírgula ou aspas que não enxergamos. Mas depois tudo funciona. Que bom que deu tudo certo.